# Can not echo into POSIX message queue

Tags: c, linux, bash, queue, posix

I try to echo a simple message into mqueue, but the terminal always returns an error about echo command.
Example:

```
/dev/mqueue$ echo domen >> my_queue
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

Command `ls -li` in folder /dev/mqueue returns:

```
total 0
29823 -rw-rw-r-- 1 domen domen 80 dec 24 14:18 my_queue
```

I create the mqueue in my C program the following way:

```
int fd_queue;
char queue_name[] = "/my_queue";
char message[4097];
struct mq_attr queue_parameters;
queue_parameters.mq_maxmsg = 5;
queue_parameters.mq_msgsize = 4096;
fd_queue = mq_open(queue_name,O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL,0664, &queue_parameters);
```

What is the problem, that I can not write into queue using terminal commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that the shell doesn't open the message queue with `mq_open()` and `echo` doesn't use `mq_send()` to write the message.  Those are the tools that are needed.  You'd need to write an `mqecho` command to write to a message queue, and an `mqread` command to read from a message queue.